# Cannot Display the Data From the object from an API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap

I am making a weather app using ReactJS and for the weather, I am using the OpenWeatherMap API. I have extracted an array and an object as they are of my interest. The array contains the kind of weather, like rainy or clear, and the object contains the temperature. I have been able to extract the weather from the array and display it on the screen, but I can't extract the temperature from the Object. The console never gave any errors. Here's the code:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function WeatherDisplay()
{
    const APIKey = "myKey";

    const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchWeather() ;
    } , []);

    const fetchWeather = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(
            "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Islamabad&units=metric&appid=" + APIKey
            );
        const weather = await data.json();

        //console.log(weather.weather);
        setWeather(weather.weather);

        console.log(weather.main);
        setTemperature(weather.main);
    } 

    return(
        <section id="w-d-p">
            <div style={
                        {
                            backgroundColor:"rgba(43, 42, 42, 0.575)",
                            width:"100%",
                            height:"100%",
                            display:"flex",
                            flexDirection:"column",
                            justifyContent:"center",
                            alignItems:"center"
                        }
                    } className="container-fluid">
                <div style={
                        {
                            display:"flex",
                            flexDirection:"column",
                            justifyContent:"center",
                            alignItems:"center"
                        }
                    } className="col-sm-12">

                    <h2 id="city">Islamabad</h2>

                    {weather.map(main => (
                        //<h2 key={main.id} id="temp">{main.temp}C</h2>
                        console.log(main.temp)
                    ))}
                    
                    {weather.map(weather => (
                        <h2 key={weather.id} id="weather">{weather.main}</h2>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default WeatherDisplay
```

Sorry I had to remove the API key.
Now in the `console.log()` before the `return()`
and it displays the temperature there in the console. I commented out the h2 tag and put  `console.log()`  there and now, the console gives `undefined` then on the next line prints the whole object and again on the next line, `undefined`. 
 
So I figured this much out that I am not doing the `map()` correctly. Please, how can I fix this? 
This is the object:

```
main {
    "temp": 28.24,
    "feels_like": 31.43,
    "temp_min": 28.24,
    "temp_max": 28.24,
    "pressure": 1005,
    "humidity": 72,
    "sea_level": 1005,
    "grnd_level": 947
}
```

Just one more thing, I am calling `useState()` two times, is that OK? Or can that be improved too? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to use 2 states for that, and while `weather` is an array but `main` is an object**

- Use one state:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState();
```

- Set the whole weather object to your state:

```
const fetchWeather = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Islamabad&units=metric&appid=" +
      APIKey
  );
  const weather = await data.json();
  setWeather(weather);
};
```

- And because `main` is an object, you then render it like so:

```
<h2 id="temp">{weather?.main && weather.main.temp}C</h2>

{weather?.weather && weather.weather.map(weather => (
  <h2 key={weather.id} id="weather">{weather.main}</h2>
))}
```

Also, your API return after the initial render, so `weather` will be null potentially causing error, so checking `weather?.weather` before render is necessary.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, it works perfectly! 
But I need a bit understanding of the code please. Is the ?. the ternary operator? 
And you didn't use the map() function on the object. Is that how we access objects?
Thanks again!

Comment: The `?.` is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which is pretty new to js. And Array.map() is for loopping through "Array" only, for objects you just make a direct reference to the variable itself.